# Google Play Store, Beta Version After Production apk

Tags: android, google-play

I have launched my application on Google Play Store, Now I have made some major changes in the application, I need to test it for all devices, That's why...

I want to upload a new apk in Beta version to test that

```
Is It possible to upload new apk in beta without affecting the production apk by increasing the version code of apk ?
```

I have searched it out but not confirmed that It will not affecting the production APK.

Comment: when you upload an apk store first check your package name and if it exist it checks the version code for new version code for new version.so with same package name it will always accept the new version code which will update your app at store....I would recommend to just use  different package name and version code to your beta version for same app

Comment: Is it possible to upload beta with the different packagename ???

Comment: No it is not possible to have different package name for same app.

Comment: have you tried beta testing panel in store

Comment: The production APK is not affected - and users who have not enrolled into the beta program will not receive the updated version. The beta (and alpha) channels exist to allow users to sign up to receive those versions of the application instead of the production one. Incrementing the version code is the correct way to track the exact versions across channels. See https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en

Comment: @AndrewBreen Thanks, Let me do it....
So I just need to upload apk with highr version code in Beta Panel and after testing finish, I just need to upload the new apk with again hegiher version code then beta.

Right ???

Comment: You can directly promote an APK from the beta channel to production - no need to re-upload when going from beta to prod.

Comment: Actually I can't see the beta version when I'm using a Google play account added in the beta tester lists.

- Version 2.0.13 deployed in production build 64
- Version 2.0.14 deployed in beta build 65 yesterday
- mytestaccount@gmail.com added in the private beta test user lists
- Log in with this account on my Android device
- Open the Google Play App and go to the app page.
- I just can download the 2.0.13 version form the google play page
Any help?